# C memory free confusion

Tags: c, memory, free

I have a short question about my code. I've created two situation or examples for testing.

example 1:

```
char *arr[1000000];
int i = 0;
for (; i < 1000000; i++){
    char *c = (char *) calloc(1, sizeof(char) * 10);
    free(c);
}
```

example 2:

```
char *arr[1000000];
int i = 0;
for (; i < 1000000; i++){
    char *c = (char *) calloc(1, sizeof(char) * 10);
    arr[i] = c;
    free(arr[i]);
    arr[i] = NULL;
}
```

The differents in examples: putting in an array before free'ing the memory.

When I run example 1 it free's all memory. When I run example 2 it doesn't free all memory.
I've searched and looked but couldn't figure it out.

Why is the result of example 2 different then example 1?

My common sense tells me example 1 and 2 should result the same, but in practice it doesn't. I use linux top for checking memory usage.

Comment: How do you know it does not free all memory?

Comment: How are you deducing that the 2nd example is not freeing all the memory?

Comment: What did you check? The RSS of the process?

Comment: I would run both of these under valgrind if you really think something is being left over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is caused by demand-paging. The process has the address space for the array (that is: pagetable entries exist for it) but there is no memory attached to it (yet). The loop assigns to (eventually) all the memory pages that belong to array[], so at the end of the loop all pages have been "faulted-in".

As a proof of concept, you can replace the loop with:

```
for (; i < 1000000; i++){
    arr[i] = "hello, world!";
}
```

And the result will probably be (almost) the same as in snippet#2

Answer (score 4):

The result are the same. I'm not sure why you think there are differences.

Comment: @Tim How do you check the memory usage?

Comment: That could be because the compiler just omits `arr` entirely in the first example (saving a few kb) because it's not used. BTW, under normal circumstances, you won't see memory usage _decrease_ with top.

Comment: @Mat: the differents in memory becomes more and more, when I run the loop more frequentely

Comment: @jpalecek: if it is so, how can I reduce the memory usage?

Comment: @TimMeijer: I'm afraid to say I don't really believe that, or you're looking at the wrong column, or measuring something else. Even if `calloc` didn't just hand out the same block at each iteration, that's at most 10MB of dynamic allocation from your process. There is no reason at all that the process should or would release that back to the OS before termination.

Comment: @Mat: I know it's difficult and I didn't believe it to. But I'm reading the answers below, they seem promosing.

Answer (score 3):

Both are the same.

Since you use `top` for reading memory the difference can be explained with compiler optimizations. For example, the array in example one can be completely optimized out.

For checking memory issues, you should use valgrind or a similar tool.